# AOC 2021 Day 1 - Integer vs. String Discrepancy

Tags: python

I have a student working on advent of code for some extra credit in our computer science class. An interesting question came up that I can't quite explain. See the following code (python):

```py
measurements = measurements.split()
#for i in range(len(measurements)):
#    measurements[i] = int(measurements[i])

count = 0

for i in range(1,len(measurements)):
    if measurements[i] > measurements[i-1]:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

When my student does not convert the data to integers, it counts 1520 increases in the data set. When he does convert to integers, he finds 1521 increases. Below is the data set if you're interested.

```
173
175
171
177
179
177
174
177
178
185
189
195
194
211
227
226
227
221
224
227
228
231
232
229
226
244
252
251
258
269
263
255
259
261
232
231
241
244
245
278
258
259
273
272
281
284
288
303
306
312
313
325
327
332
335
345
346
328
329
327
330
325
326
325
351
352
353
363
364
382
402
401
380
370
371
348
359
357
366
386
401
387
388
404
409
430
435
441
475
469
475
473
478
510
507
508
510
502
500
512
517
521
519
532
533
537
538
540
541
545
556
548
543
549
561
562
563
562
561
572
574
575
568
569
570
579
591
590
602
601
581
583
593
590
591
577
576
579
581
563
559
563
564
567
569
570
582
579
601
598
583
589
591
597
611
618
621
622
641
657
658
661
631
633
646
647
652
667
670
676
680
681
683
681
687
690
683
687
690
695
691
693
696
695
700
697
696
700
713
696
693
698
701
700
699
690
692
693
696
722
744
746
758
763
768
782
776
777
787
797
800
801
789
814
815
812
790
791
790
804
813
841
845
844
848
855
847
855
858
859
858
860
867
868
869
877
887
888
895
896
904
905
907
923
932
944
945
950
955
965
990
1019
1017
1025
1040
1041
1066
1060
1033
1034
1047
1057
1060
1061
1068
1071
1080
1081
1090
1096
1097
1098
1099
1093
1096
1100
1101
1112
1118
1119
1121
1123
1125
1126
1152
1155
1149
1161
1166
1178
1181
1182
1189
1190
1176
1169
1183
1196
1183
1205
1207
1198
1200
1186
1172
1162
1177
1179
1175
1163
1164
1170
1168
1171
1173
1172
1174
1175
1172
1173
1167
1169
1173
1176
1177
1178
1179
1181
1185
1186
1196
1183
1181
1176
1190
1200
1216
1240
1238
1234
1224
1247
1257
1258
1246
1233
1234
1223
1229
1231
1232
1231
1232
1249
1255
1254
1257
1268
1298
1300
1302
1325
1337
1339
1345
1348
1336
1341
1342
1343
1344
1343
1336
1351
1360
1362
1359
1357
1358
1364
1370
1372
1373
1374
1378
1409
1390
1398
1410
1411
1417
1418
1431
1450
1451
1452
1456
1468
1469
1472
1475
1465
1469
1453
1457
1458
1474
1464
1454
1457
1460
1467
1469
1470
1455
1456
1468
1476
1498
1502
1500
1514
1522
1529
1528
1516
1511
1516
1521
1503
1523
1498
1515
1527
1526
1527
1556
1567
1586
1607
1616
1615
1611
1612
1621
1599
1600
1601
1625
1632
1633
1628
1656
1644
1646
1669
1671
1675
1676
1682
1681
1658
1657
1671
1669
1668
1669
1670
1691
1708
1709
1708
1724
1731
1738
1748
1766
1767
1769
1756
1757
1758
1759
1760
1773
1775
1777
1780
1782
1793
1813
1795
1796
1798
1797
1804
1806
1811
1812
1813
1818
1822
1829
1824
1814
1811
1806
1825
1844
1847
1837
1841
1844
1836
1825
1828
1841
1846
1839
1840
1847
1856
1869
1870
1871
1879
1884
1890
1888
1859
1861
1873
1870
1871
1876
1885
1886
1887
1888
1887
1895
1888
1889
1891
1890
1884
1885
1854
1857
1860
1841
1837
1838
1841
1859
1863
1865
1866
1864
1853
1855
1865
1867
1875
1876
1877
1880
1877
1876
1886
1894
1901
1903
1910
1901
1903
1905
1911
1913
1928
1938
1940
1946
1956
1951
1953
1955
1961
1957
1960
1967
1966
1970
1976
1979
1980
1979
1967
1974
1980
1974
1975
1976
2005
2012
2015
2022
2023
2024
2018
2017
2024
2041
2042
2043
2074
2075
2077
2084
2090
2091
2096
2097
2100
2103
2090
2063
2081
2082
2079
2095
2093
2095
2103
2084
2093
2098
2116
2123
2124
2123
2117
2115
2120
2121
2132
2138
2146
2158
2162
2163
2167
2177
2178
2183
2178
2198
2174
2187
2196
2221
2224
2228
2232
2237
2238
2257
2262
2263
2266
2280
2287
2293
2280
2281
2289
2290
2289
2291
2307
2316
2322
2321
2320
2335
2339
2345
2348
2357
2360
2361
2367
2375
2380
2382
2389
2398
2384
2388
2390
2367
2369
2371
2366
2370
2371
2379
2364
2365
2368
2369
2370
2377
2378
2390
2392
2398
2402
2393
2404
2417
2441
2446
2453
2459
2462
2463
2464
2476
2477
2481
2482
2483
2477
2481
2489
2500
2504
2491
2490
2487
2474
2475
2476
2478
2489
2491
2498
2501
2513
2514
2532
2546
2547
2553
2559
2562
2580
2588
2590
2602
2601
2608
2613
2616
2623
2626
2651
2652
2654
2650
2651
2654
2658
2657
2660
2654
2668
2669
2662
2665
2647
2660
2670
2672
2680
2677
2678
2677
2684
2677
2678
2684
2702
2703
2707
2727
2728
2738
2739
2738
2757
2759
2766
2771
2775
2788
2790
2794
2797
2800
2798
2801
2800
2802
2803
2804
2831
2820
2821
2824
2827
2813
2816
2826
2827
2829
2834
2835
2841
2849
2854
2855
2867
2877
2894
2900
2918
2917
2898
2899
2901
2902
2903
2901
2919
2920
2931
2939
2945
2946
2934
2936
2947
2956
2955
2958
2946
2947
2951
2955
2957
2960
2964
2965
2974
2976
2992
3009
3014
3015
2997
2996
3003
3000
3006
3026
3019
3031
3012
3013
3020
3010
3014
3018
3019
3031
3007
3017
3018
3031
3033
3025
3037
3039
3033
3000
3001
3003
3014
3016
3034
3033
3035
3038
3040
3038
3020
3018
3020
3021
3039
3043
3034
3036
3043
3059
3074
3076
3090
3096
3103
3101
3102
3113
3114
3115
3119
3127
3146
3140
3145
3146
3147
3151
3152
3153
3154
3144
3149
3157
3163
3172
3175
3180
3206
3207
3212
3215
3211
3212
3220
3229
3230
3226
3227
3256
3296
3299
3301
3303
3301
3302
3308
3324
3323
3313
3314
3317
3318
3317
3330
3358
3360
3369
3363
3368
3371
3377
3381
3385
3382
3379
3381
3383
3385
3386
3389
3388
3392
3396
3393
3391
3393
3394
3398
3400
3403
3404
3408
3424
3425
3426
3424
3415
3417
3420
3439
3442
3447
3454
3478
3480
3477
3478
3470
3472
3477
3476
3477
3479
3509
3519
3542
3547
3548
3564
3565
3569
3570
3584
3591
3590
3589
3598
3603
3605
3609
3608
3628
3624
3644
3652
3654
3648
3650
3652
3659
3661
3675
3676
3690
3692
3699
3700
3702
3703
3706
3715
3719
3720
3725
3721
3730
3722
3740
3750
3751
3752
3761
3763
3778
3777
3778
3780
3777
3794
3793
3792
3802
3803
3806
3817
3814
3823
3824
3825
3826
3831
3834
3835
3844
3856
3857
3864
3879
3904
3906
3923
3933
3935
3934
3935
3937
3935
3944
3941
3936
3937
3935
3936
3935
3937
3938
3949
3950
3949
3952
3953
3980
3989
3990
3991
3992
3988
3993
4003
3969
3959
3964
3973
3981
3987
3986
3975
3982
3981
3983
3981
3984
3992
3991
3984
3999
4003
4004
3996
3992
4035
4043
4042
4034
4027
4051
4052
4048
4051
4049
4060
4059
4062
4061
4063
4062
4053
4056
4067
4055
4057
4058
4072
4077
4075
4060
4057
4058
4061
4060
4061
4060
4070
4088
4097
4093
4105
4107
4105
4103
4105
4109
4086
4111
4112
4115
4110
4118
4119
4127
4128
4129
4130
4134
4136
4135
4138
4139
4140
4135
4158
4137
4138
4158
4157
4154
4156
4175
4176
4179
4184
4198
4196
4199
4180
4188
4193
4192
4201
4200
4192
4207
4220
4218
4230
4229
4247
4248
4249
4253
4254
4256
4265
4266
4272
4268
4273
4295
4296
4305
4295
4310
4311
4312
4311
4314
4307
4305
4294
4306
4321
4316
4326
4330
4331
4337
4336
4337
4338
4340
4342
4345
4347
4345
4370
4384
4405
4406
4419
4420
4435
4439
4443
4445
4447
4431
4424
4433
4418
4417
4416
4417
4420
4424
4440
4442
4454
4461
4481
4483
4479
4480
4484
4485
4495
4498
4499
4524
4527
4528
4539
4541
4545
4543
4559
4569
4571
4568
4573
4570
4571
4580
4579
4580
4583
4588
4589
4590
4597
4632
4625
4626
4618
4621
4632
4642
4644
4647
4650
4665
4669
4666
4673
4674
4677
4681
4686
4651
4657
4658
4664
4665
4667
4685
4688
4695
4712
4714
4715
4717
4731
4734
4738
4737
4743
4745
4752
4753
4748
4763
4768
4769
4771
4774
4801
4802
4830
4845
4850
4847
4873
4883
4884
4885
4886
4887
4896
4891
4913
4914
4937
4938
4953
4959
4979
4984
4990
4982
4979
5008
5007
5008
5004
5015
5017
5038
5066
5067
5069
5078
5091
5101
5086
5088
5086
5092
5097
5098
5088
5070
5072
5083
5082
5073
5077
5080
5076
5073
5065
5066
5068
5069
5081
5082
5084
5083
5086
5089
5092
5095
5130
5133
5119
5129
5130
5138
5140
5148
5147
5150
5151
5155
5163
5188
5190
5192
5189
5196
5180
5191
5193
5197
5182
5162
5163
5147
5154
5155
5168
5207
5216
5223
5228
5227
5229
5221
5218
5221
5219
5220
5230
5259
5260
5233
5256
5258
5251
5246
5230
5234
5242
5245
5260
5261
5269
5281
5285
5296
5297
5296
5297
5298
5313
5314
5313
5319
5313
5322
5324
5325
5333
5346
5354
5355
5345
5347
5349
5350
5352
5339
5349
5345
5361
5362
5363
5404
5398
5424
5415
5420
5433
5435
5436
5437
5438
5455
5454
5460
5455
5453
5454
5466
5469
5471
5481
5482
5502
5503
5501
5484
5460
5461
5465
5466
5470
5454
5460
5486
5482
5483
5502
5512
5514
5516
5518
5525
5526
5521
5515
5518
5521
5528
5539
5557
5561
5577
5571
5572
5579
5576
5577
5589
5592
5595
5596
5595
5601
5587
5560
5563
5562
5571
5598
5606
5621
5636
5637
5663
5665
5678
5677
5678
5679
5684
5687
5684
5688
5691
5690
5693
5696
5707
5725
5727
5731
5734
5738
5748
5767
5768
5763
5767
5758
5760
5791
5777
5778
5782
5773
5776
5777
5791
5792
5793
5795
5781
5786
5793
5805
5807
5818
5822
5821
5826
5827
5846
5847
5864
5886
5878
5873
5868
5878
5876
5881
5876
5888
5890
5893
5894
5895
5900
5907
5908
5915
5916
5937
5936
5927
5938
5945
5944
5935
5942
5943
5945
5948
5977
5985
5975
5985
5998
5999
5996
6027
6047
6031
6033
6034
6022
6023
6025
6030
6029
6030
6034
6046
6055
6061
6058
6067
6070
6077
6069
6088
6084
6090
6100
6102
6107
6111
6108
6103
6104
6114
6118
6107
6114
6102
6112
6113
6115
6116
6139
6135
6143
6154
6155
6160
6163
6160
6163
6169
6184
6176
6199
6205
6204
6219
6222
6231
6207
6218
6219
6221
6222
6221
6200
6194
6203
6204
6210
6209
6210
6209
6210
6230
6238
6239
6245
6249
6264
6271
6262
6275
6252
6253
6240
6245
6219
6220
6221
6222
6225
6231
6236
6238
6267
6272
6273
6278
6287
6286
6287
6281
6264
6269
6270
6274
6247
6248
6259
6264
6267
6276
6281
6286
6284
6289
6287
6275
6247
6263
6261
6264
6265
6270
6271
6272
6271
6280
6282
6283
6291
6302
6303
6315
6335
6361
6358
6359
6362
6363
6349
6348
6355
6357
6358
6357
6375
6374
6367
6342
6350
6354
6353
6354
6357
6369
6371
6382
6384
6371
6403
6402
6412
6413
6415
6416
6417
6418
6419
6420
6438
6436
6438
6443
6454
6440
6439
6431
6442
6441
6444
6446
6450
6422
6424
6418
6426
6437
6438
6439
6449
6451
6452
6463
6464
6475
6492
6499
6506
6519
6548
6545
6543
6556
6565
6567
6564
6553
6554
6556
6564
6584
6580
6581
6582
6584
6585
6586
6595
6596
6595
6598
6575
6594
6595
6593
6591
6602
6603
6575
6573
6577
6586
6587
6615
6624
6647
6677
6678
6679
6683
6682
6684
6689
6704
6709
6723
6751
6754
6755
6757
6758
6774
6787
6791
6816
6837
6838
6846
6847
6845
6847
6850
6864
6863
6853
6874
6875
6874
6883
6891
6899
6918
6920
6921
6937
6934
6935
6951
6950
6969
6971
6976
6978
6979
6987
6989
6987
6989
6991
6990
6991
6980
6979
6963
6964
6968
6972
7000
6992
7003
7006
7019
7022
7028
7040
7035
7034
7055
7063
7065
7066
7071
7079
7092
7102
7118
7115
7121
```

Thanks!

Comment: What should this evaluate to? `"100" > "99"`

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: If you have students, you really should know how string comparison is different from integer comparison

Comment: Apologies, Pranav.

I am a Mathematics teacher. I have only coded in the past for a hobby, but this was more experience than the other teachers at my school....so here I am. Trying to give my students the best explanations possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepancy you notice comes from the following comparison:

```
>>> 1019 > 990
True
>>> "1019" > "990"
False
```

Strings are compared by checking the lexicographical order of their consecutive characters. In this case "1" < "9" which causes the problem.